# How to make dynamic post's preview image for facebook in blogspot.com?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, blogger

I would like to add post's preview image to facebook Open Graph meta tag.
One possible solution is to use  ***data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl***:

```
<meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl' property='og:image'/>
```

However, the default post image thumbnail which is created by Blogger is too small (72px × 72px), and it doesn't look really nice when facebook tries to stretch it while creating the post's story based on this image thumbnail (facebook says "all the images referenced by og:image must be at least 200px in both dimensions").

So, the question is:

is there any way to retrieve somehow the image's url from the post's body and insert it into facebook Open Graph meta tag which was mentioned above?
(let's say every post of my blog  has image tag inside its body:

http://loveclubhouse.blogspot.com/)

Comment: Why can't you change the `default post image thumbnail` to a higher quality one?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You can. It's kind of sloppy looking, but functional. Here the `og:image` property from my blog. As you see it is actually grabbing an image from my Facebook profile:

```
<meta content='http://sphotos.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash3/538645_3357819035748_1577184006_2624573_712999292_n.jpg' property='og:image'/>
```

When you load an image from your photo library in Facebook, you can usually right click on it and select "View Image". When you do that, you'll see the URL to the actual image as it is stored by Facebook. So long as the image is publicly accessible, there won't be any problems.

You can see it in action at [my blog](http://formlesspoet.blogspot.com/search/label/free%20verse) if you decide to click Recommend (the current page) or Like (of an individual post). :)

Comment: I can't use right click and add image url to meta tag manually for every post in my blog. It's a blogger's template which is the same for each post. I'm asking if there is a  possibility to retrieve the image url by means of blogger language (such as regular expressions or similar).

Comment: Oh I see. Not that I know of. But if I learn how later I'll try to remember to come back here again.